# What to do for installing driver files?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

I've downloaded an ethernet driver from [here](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/4401.php). It is packed into a zip archive that contains three files, with extensions `.sys`, `.inf`, and `.cat`. Now, where I am supposed to put those files to install the driver, and what should I do afterwards (if anything needs to be done)?

The manual on the page I linked to says "double-click Setup.exe", but, well, there is nothing like that in the archive. [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the subject is not helpful either, as it focuses developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "Add Hardware" option in Control Panel, and when selecting driver sources tell it to search the directory that has all three files. (Alternatively, choose manual mode and use "Have disk…" to select the same directory.)

Answer (score 3):

- Open Device Manager (Start -> type Device Manager)
- Right click the hardware you want to update and select properties
- In the driver tab, click Update Driver, select the folder you've saved the files in, follow the wizard.